# multiple asynchronous tasks finish one after another and allow user to do other work till get finished all tasks

Tags: wpf, async-await, task

my application is WPf and we have data service.

I would like to call async data service task to do some work and return once it done. while async task is doing his job my client can do other work.

but when i would like to call 10 same task by for loop and i want to do each task one after the other task but not parallel. Also my client can continue other work till all 10 task get finished.

if i use task[i].wait() will not allow my client to continue other work. client cannot do anything else till each task get done.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking calls like `.Wait()` and `.Result` wont let the UI continue

Use async/await, like for example in a button click event

```
public async void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < someParameter; i++) { 
        await importExportServiceClient.ClientEntryImportExportAsync(ImpExpobj, start, end, chunk);//for running task to finish 
    }
}
```

each task will be awaited in turn without blocking the client. Allowing the client to continue other work till all tasks are completed.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)